# How do I change a single character in a string

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a pacman game using a Data Grid View in C# forms. I have created the game map from a string:

```
private string INITMAP =               "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww"+
                                       "wkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwwwwkwwwwwwkwkw"+
                                       "wkwwkkkkkkwwkkkkkwkw"+
                                       "wkkkkwwwwkwwkwkwkkkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwkkkkwwkwkwkwkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwwwwkwwkwwwkwkw"+
                                       "wkwwkkbbbbbbbkkkkwkw"+
                                       "wkwwwwbwbbbwbwwkwkkw"+
                                       "wkkkkkbwbbbwbwwkkwkw"+
                                       "wkwkwwbwbbbwbkkkwkkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwbwwwwwbwwwwwkw"+
                                       "wkkkkkbbbbbbbkkkkkkw"+
                                       "wkwwwwkwkwwwwkwkwwkw"+
                                       "wkwkkkkwkkkwwkwkkwkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwkwkwkwwkkkwwkw"+
                                       "wkkkkwkwkwkwwkwkkkkw"+
                                       "wkwwkwkwkwkwwkwwkwkw"+
                                       "wkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkw"+
                                       "wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww";
public void Draw()
int totalCells = NROWSCOLUMNS * NROWSCOLUMNS;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalCells; i++)
        {
            int nRow = i / NROWSCOLUMNS;
            int nColumn = i % NROWSCOLUMNS;

            switch (map.Substring(i, 1))
            {
                case "w":
                    Rows[nRow].Cells[nColumn].Value = wall;
                    break;
                case "k":
                    Rows[nRow].Cells[nColumn].Value = kibble;
                    break;
                case "b":
                    Rows[nRow].Cells[nColumn].Value = blank;
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Unidentified value in string");
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I then draw the images into each cell using the above code.

When pacman hits a kibble, I need it to replace a 'k' in the string to a 'b'. For example if the kibble was at (1,1) on the data grid view, I need to some how change the 'k' at position 21 in the INITMAP string to a 'b' while keeping everything else the same.

I can't just change the image of that cell to a blank image as the game map draws to the grid view on each timer tick, so the blank would be replaced with that kibble again.

Comment: Strings in .Net don't change. You have to make new ones, using things like SubString() or Insert()... or you could use a 2D array, which would probably make a lot more sense here :)

Comment: Strings are immutable, so that means that for any change you need to make a new string. To replace a character in the middle of a string you need to get the string before that character, and the string after that character (2 new strings), which you then join with the new character to make the full string. This can be done with `"string".Substring()` and `string.Concat(s1, s2, s3)`. I would advise against this and suggest using an array which represents the state of each cell. Note that if you're just changing DataGrid cells, you can render them to a string at the point of saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to get the coordinate of the letter and as Joel Coehoorn mentioned, use substring like this:

```
str = str.Substring(0, coordinate) + 'b' + str.Substring(coordinate+1, str.length())
```

where coordinate is the position of the character in your string.

Comment: Thanks! This might turn out to be simple but would you also have any advice on how to get the position of the letter to change in the string based off of an X and Y position from the data grid view? For example, if pacman's position is at (10, 5) on the grid view, how would I calculate the position of the letter to change in the string? I've tried different ways but it always seems to change a completely different cell in the grid to a blank.

Comment: The way that you would do this is since the width of each row is 20 characters long, you would just multiply the y-coordinate, in this case 5, by 20. Then you would add 1 + the x-coordinate to get 111 in this case. This is assuming that (10,5) means that it is the 6th row and eleventh column because indexes start at 0. If (10,5) means the 5th row and tenth column, then you would just multiply 20 *(5-1) + (10-1). The number you get is the characters position in the String. If you found my answer to be useful, please mark it as useful. Thank you!